# Spring Boot with Jersey Multipart File upload not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jersey, multipartform-data

I am using Spring Boot Jersey in my application and Trying to upload Multipart File using REST , but whenever I making API call , it always give below exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
at 
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2669)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2636)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1083)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:347)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:85)
... 32 common frames omitted
```

I  have tried all different things like setting properties in application.properties and also create be config bean.Please see below.
I really appreciate if some one can help me to resolve this issue.

Approach 1.

```
spring.http.multipart.enabled=true
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=1MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.resolve-lazily=false
```

Approach 2.

```
@Configuration
public class MultiPartConfig {

  @Bean
  public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize(1024L);
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
  }
}
```

My API endpoint.

```
@POST
@Path("/picture")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response loadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
                         @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition,
                         @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to add the `MultipartFeaure` to your configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

  public JerseyConfiguration(){
    register(MultiPartFeature.class);

  }
}
```